# AngularJS changing model value in one controller triggers model update in others

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

### EDIT:

Ok I update the example to avoid the loop problem, so back to the original question it sill recalculate B model objects.

In this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qn2Wa/

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="A"><input ng-model="m">
        {{a()}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="B"><input ng-model="m">
        {{b()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function A($scope) {
    $scope.m='a';
    var counter = 0;
    $scope.a = function(){
        console.log("A " + counter++);
        return $scope.m;
    }
}
function B($scope) {
    $scope.m='b';
    var counter = 0;
    $scope.b = function(){
        console.log("B " + counter++);
        return $scope.m;
    }
}
```

as soon as I change the input value in controller A, it will call b() which is in a totally separate controller.
Why would it recalculate the model objects in the other controllers? Is there a way to avoid this?

If you see the console log you can see that B is printed every time you type something in A input field which is in a totally separate controller and scope.

---

JUST FOR REFERENCE I keep the original code for the question here.
It has error since it is updating the model in the function call as pointed out by some of the comments, this is fixed in the above code. The error could be moved to a separate question.

http://jsfiddle.net/m8xtA/

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="A"><input ng-model="m">
        {{a()}} - {{counter}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="B"><input ng-model="m">
        {{b()}} - {{counter}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function A($scope) {
    $scope.m='a';
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.a = function(){
        $scope.counter++;
        return $scope.m;
    }
}
function B($scope) {
    $scope.m='b';
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.b = function(){
        $scope.counter++;
        return $scope.m;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have this error in the console: `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Comment: @Cherniv can you explain why this code would produce that error?

Comment: @DavinTryon : binding a function (i.e. `{{a()}}`) is a mistake due to angular's internal mechanism and its `$digest` loop which will call `a()` in an endless loop

Comment: @Utopik do you know of a doc or blog that explains this, just curious. Thanks.

Comment: Question is edited with the example to avoid the digest error.

Comment: @Utopik: binding to a function is very normal thing to do, let's say a() calculate the class name for an element on the page <span ng-class='a()'> instead of {{a()}}

Comment: In your case, it is not a "very normal thing". Your new example "works" because you break two-way data binding ( counter is not part of the scope anymore, so angular can't play with it ).
You can bind function if your function does not make any change in the scope (as `sza` pointed it out ). 
Why it calls b() function? After each modification of the scope, angular check for changes. How can angular know if the result of b() is new or not, without calling it ? So angular calls b() every time. 
It is not obvious, but believe me, using `$watch` is a good practice, and the easiest correct way ;)

Comment: And in your example ( `<span ng-class='a()'>` ), a() will be executed every time a change is made. ( see http://jsfiddle.net/qn2Wa/5/, check your console )

Comment: It does make sense that a() is called since it is in the same scope as A controller. But b() is in totally different controller and they don't share the scope. So angular should know that changing model object in one scope won't change values in a totally different scope.

Comment: And in the updated example calling function b() does not change any scope variable, so I believe it is a normal thing now.

Comment: @danial I recommend you post it on github and the creator could have a better interpretation. It seems a normal behavior to be but I am not sure.

Comment: @DavinTryon http://www.thinkster.io/pick/PQ1TiYfWQf/digest

Comment: @danial : from the above link, you can see $digest is applied to $rootScope, not the current scope. That's why b() is called even if it is from a different scope.

Comment: @Utopik yes I found that in the angular code too, and tried to patch it locally so it would just apply it to ancestors and children but it won't be ideal solution since I don't want to keep patching the new versions. I posted it on [angularjs github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3960) and the response was that it is the intended behaviour of angularjs.

Answer (score 2):

here is a working solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/m8xtA/1/

Using [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) is a good way to accomplish that.

```
function A($scope) {
    $scope.m='a';
    $scope.counter = 0;
    //executed each time `m' is changed
    $scope.$watch('m',function(){
        $scope.counter++;
    })
}
function B($scope) {
    $scope.m='b';
    $scope.counter = 0;
    //executed each time `m' is changed
    $scope.$watch('m',function(){
        $scope.counter++;
    })
}
```

Hope this help, cheers

Comment: I updated the original question. I don't want to accomplish what you are suggesting here. I just want to avoid updating one controller model object to recalculate the other controller's.

Answer (score 1):

During the template rendering, if you change the model or object used for binding the template, it will trigger a new rendering cycle which will end up with a endless loop. It will cause this error `'Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!'.`

In your code, when `{{a()}}` is being rendered, it modifies the object `counter` by the statement `$scope.counter++;`, which will trigger the endless loop since in the template `{{counter}}` needs to be rendered.

(What you see is caused by the broken evaluation, so you will see some funky behavior.)

Comment: Just curious, why then if you declare a different `counter` do you still get the same issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/Cnw7R/

Comment: @DavinTryon Not the case you demonstrated. Since `a()` update the `counter`, and you have `{{counter}}` in the template of controller `A` as well, then it causes the problem. Try to comment `$scope.counter++;` and you will not see the error any more. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to avoid this digest issue. Still the original question remains.