# How to prevent ng-repeat from triggering every time the model changes (involves Firebase/angularFire)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

I am building the DOM using data synced/fetched from Firebase with angularFire.
Every DOM element is built with this simple directive:

```
angular.module('App')
  .directive('acmsElement', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div> ',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {elem: '='},
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        var el = angular.element(scope.elem.tag);
        if(scope.elem.content){
          el.text(scope.elem.content);
        }
        if(scope.elem.attributes) {
          el.attr(scope.elem.attributes);
        }
        element.append(el);
      }
    };
  });
```

and all elements are rendered on the website sequentially using ng-repeat and every element/model is made editable with textarea:

```
<div ng-repeat="el in elems">
  <acms-element elem="el">
    <textarea style="width: 100%" ng-model="el.content"></textarea>
  </acms-element>
</div>
```

In the Firebase the nodes are stored as an array, so it is straight forward to display them in the right order using ng-repeat. The problem starts when I try to edit any model  bound to a textarea above, the ng-repeats its work on every keystroke. This causes that the focus on the textarea is lost, the page flickers as it is rendered, and most annoyingly, I can input only one character at a time before the page is re-generated. Not sure how to tackle the problem.
Thank you for your time,
Jared

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue here: [hanging-model-value-in-one-controller-triggers-model-update-in-others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686017/angularjs-changing-model-value-in-one-controller-triggers-model-update-in-others).

Every time a model object is changed the digest cycle is called on the $rootScope which will update all the scopes.

A workaround would be to have two separate model variables for Firebase and actual elements so the changes in your textarea will not call the Firebase. Then have a $timeout() function to "sync" (going through properties recursively and update/delete them only if they are changed) those two model objects in the background.

Comment: Yeah, been thinking of a similar solution, but not sure how to implement it. I'm relatively new to angular and I still struggle to recognize which scope I am working with at any given moment :). As an experiment I replaced Firebase with actual, hard-coded object, but then, with the way it is coded right now, there is no link between textareas and what is rendered on the page - I can type freely but nothing is reflected in the rendered element. Should I use $watch or $digest in some way to enable the binding? Also my experiment shows that it is the angularFire which does the linking.

Comment: So I guess I should investigate angularFire in the search for the solution to my problem, no?

Comment: My suggestion is to have the Firebase or whatever code that supposed to updates the value in the textarea to upload a model variable that is not bound to textarea like "myModel1". Then have your textarea to bind to "myModel2". Then you can have 2 $watch on myModel1 and myModel2 and "sync" the data between these two models. If you put up a sample jsfiddler page I can update it to show you what I mean.